# using regex with preg_match to compare with array of phone numbers in a for each loop

Tags: php

I am trying to validate phone numbers starting 04 or +61. I am getting the phone Numbers from database then using for each loop, to loop through each phone number and using preg_grep to validate. It works fine when I put only one phone number. But when I use a variable (an array ) it doesn't display any result.

```
$records[] = $row;

$PhoneHome = $row['Phonehome'];

//print_r($PhoneHome);
$phoneNumberValidate = "/^(?:\+?61|0)4 ?(?:(?:[01] ?[0-9]|2 ?[0-57-9]|3 ?[1-9]|4 ?[7-9]|5 ?[018]) ?[0-9]|3 ?0 ?[0-5])(?: ?[0-9]){5}/";

foreach ($records as $r ){
     if(preg_grep($phoneNumberValidate,$PhoneHome,$matches))
     {
          print_r($matches);
     }
}
```

Comment: you never use $r in your loop

Comment: @tim, are you saying I should be using $r or $r['Phonehome'] instead of $PhoneHome ?

Comment: ............yes

Answer (score 0):

$PhoneHome[] = $row[(Phonehome'];

print_r($PhoneHome)

foreach ($records as $row )

{

$phoneNumberValidate = "/^(?:+?61|0)4 ?(?:(?:[01] ?[0-9]|2 ?[0-57-9]|3 ?[1-9]|4 ?[7-9]|5 ?[018]) ?[0-9]|3 ?0 ?[0-5])(?: ?[0-9]){5}/";

if(preg_match_all($phoneNumberValidate,$row[Phonehome'],$matches))

{
    print_r($matches)

```
}
```

}